# Regarding SQL Distinct clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to output the following data with only one row for each location. Right now it shows:
120....
120...
120...

Im trying to get it to sum all the values up into one row for 120, one row for 123, one row for 128, ect. I think this has something to do with DISTINCT clauses but I'm kinda brain fried looking at this...

```
SELECT ICLOCATION.LOCATION,
       ICLOCATION.NAME,
       ITEMMAST.ITEM,
       ITEMMAST.DESCRIPTION,
       ITEMLOC.SOH_QTY,
       OnOrder,
       AllocQty,
       SUM(ITEMLOC.SOH_QTY + t.OnOrder - t.AllocQty) AS NetOnHand
FROM   (SELECT ITEMLOC.ITEM,
               SUM(ISNULL(ITEMLOC.ONORDER_QTY, 0) + ITEMLOC.INTRANS_QTY + ITEMLOC.WIP_QTY)                                 AS OnOrder,
               SUM(ITEMLOC.ALLOC_QTY + ITEMLOC.UNALLOC_QTY + ITEMLOC.BACKORD_QTY + ITEMLOC.IN_PROC_QTY + ITEMLOC.HOLD_QTY) AS AllocQty
        FROM   ITEMLOC
        GROUP  BY ITEMLOC.ITEM) t
       INNER JOIN ITEMLOC
         ON ITEMLOC.ITEM = t.ITEM
       INNER JOIN ITEMMAST
         ON ITEMLOC.ITEM = ITEMMAST.ITEM
       INNER JOIN ICLOCATION
         ON ITEMLOC.COMPANY = ICLOCATION.COMPANY
WHERE  ( ICLOCATION.LOCATION = '120'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = '123'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = '128'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = '129'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = 'HD41D'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = 'HD21H'
          OR ICLOCATION.LOCATION = 'HD91H' )
       AND ITEMMAST.ITEM = '0210950'
GROUP  BY ITEMMAST.ITEM,
          ICLOCATION.LOCATION,
          ICLOCATION.NAME,
          ITEMMAST.DESCRIPTION,
          ITEMLOC.SOH_QTY,
          ITEMLOC.ITEM,
          OnOrder,
          AllocQty
ORDER  BY ICLOCATION.LOCATION,
          ITEMMAST.ITEM
```

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag as it is contradicted by the more specific SQL Server 2008 one.

Comment: Can you post your results?  You should be receiving distinct records for each field in your `GROUP BY` at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pare down your `GROUP BY`s. It's first going to group by `ITEMMAST.ITEM`, and then `ICLOCATION.LOCATION`. Either switch the order or get rid of the `ITEM`.

Also, unrelated, you may want to clean it up a bit by using the IN operator in your WHERE statement.  i.e.

```
ICLOCATION.LOCATION IN ('120', '123', '128', '129', 'HD41D', 'HD21H', 'HD91H')
```

Comment: good call on the IN. As far as the GROUP BYs, how should I approach that? If I take out ITEMMAST.ITEM, it doesn't work because its not in the aggregate function or GROUP BY clause

Comment: If you take it out of the `GROUP BY`, you'll also have to remove it from the select list. It makes sense if you think about it - since it's not a part of the grouping, there could be multiple values per group.

Comment: I took ITEM out, but my location numbers still arent grouping.

Comment: Take a look at anything else that could be causing multiple records.  One of those other columns must also be responsible for having more than one value for each LOCATION.

Comment: each of the other values have multiple values now that you mention it. If I want to sum them all into one value for each location, how would I approach that?